# Set operations in python

Tags: python, math, set, set-intersection

I am looking for a single set operation to accomplish both the cases below. Is there a way to do this python?

Case 1:
`a = set([1,2])` and `b = set([1,2,3])`
I want a result `[1,2]`, which is a straightforward intersection. Now `set(a)` could be empty and performing intersection on empty set with any other set would lead to empty set.

Case 2:
`a = set([])` and `b = set([1,2,3]) => set([1,2,3])` i.e. set b

How can I achieve case 1 and case 2 with one set operation.

Comment: What operation is case 2 supposed to be? Union?

Comment: Do you want both `union` and `intersection` to happen in one operation ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking -- it *looks* like you want a single set operation that has contradictory behavior. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In one case you want an intersection, in the other you essentially want to do nothing. I don't think there's any way to express that other than as "if `a` is empty, do nothing".

Comment: Maybe `c=(a&b) if a else b`

Comment: My bad, let's simplify can we do "intersection" and "union" according to the set(a) value. I don't want to use "if" conditional to check it's value.

Comment: You're not going to find a better way than using `if`.

Comment: What do you mean intersection *and* union? And why these restrictions like no if? You think there's a builtin operation for every conceivable weird construction?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Maybe you can tell us **why** you want what you want.

Comment: Maybe `(b, a & b)[bool(a)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `and` and `or`, which will short-circuit to produce the desired results:

```
>>> a = {1,2}
>>> b = {1,2,3}
>>> a and a&b or b
{1, 2}
>>> a = {}
>>> b = {1,2,3}
>>> a and a&b or b
{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: I don't think this gives the intended result (the empty intersection) for `a={1,2}`, `b={3,4}`

Comment: You're right. I didn't think to test that case. @ProgramQuestions, can you unaccept this so I can delete it?

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is "if `a` is non-empty, give me the intersection; otherwise just give me `b`", then what you want is:

```
result = (a&b) if a else b
```

"I don't want to use `if` conditional to check its value" does not make much sense as a requirement. This is what `if` is for: varying behaviour based on some condition.